# How to align both of comments and macro of multiple lines with space instead tabs for C/C++ code?

Tags: comment, align

This is my configuration in init.el for C/C++ code which is default value in linux kernel:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
```

I'm using this style and won't change it to `nil`.

And indentation and alignment work perfectly when I'm writing C/C++ code.

But I found that when I try to manually align multiple lines of comments (comment at the end of a line) or macro, the `M-x align` or `M-x align-regexp` command will align them with tabs, sometimes tab+space, this is really annoying, since when I tried to view the file in other tools such as vim, less or in `git diff`, the alignment will be messed up, and I work with other people, so I cannot change all the tool.

The easiest thing to do is to change Emacs `align` and `align-regexp`.
So how can I make `M-x align` and `M-x align-regexp` align all the multiple macros and comments with pure space instead tab (or tab+space)?

Original:

[image]

Current `align` or `align-regexp`, I enable `whitespace-mode` to show the tab/space, you can see that all the blanks of the alignment of macros and comments are tabs instead spaces.(If the original block contains multiple spaces, it will be space+tab):
[image]

Desired `align` or `align-regexp`:
[image]

How can I modify `align`/`align-regexp` or define a new function for both macros and comments of multiple lines?

---

**UPDATE**:

I already come up a solution, it is not smart, but it is enough. If anyone got any better idea, welcome.

https://gist.github.com/c02y/53f3dc97f2c985e89b86095d6a27a1c3

Comment: There's some advice available at the Emacs Wiki: _[Indenting C](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC)_

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing anything about this, can't you just define your own `my-align` or `my-align-regexp` command that invokes the standard command after binding `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil`?

If, *in that context*, you want spaces only, then just turn the mode off in that context (and turn it back on again when the command is done).

E.g., something like this (untested):

```el
(defun my-align (beg end &optional separate rules exclude-rules)
  "`align', but with `indent-tabs-mode' bound to nil."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((indent-tabs-mode  nil))
    (align beg end separate rules exclude-rules)))

(defun my-align-regexp (beg end regexp &optional group spacing repeat)
  "`align-regexp', but with `indent-tabs-mode' bound to nil."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((indent-tabs-mode  nil))
    (align-regexp beg end regexp group spacing repeat)))
```

Well, looking quickly at `align.el` I'm guessing that might not work (but you might try it).  `align-to-tab-stop` has `indent-tabs-mode` as its default value, suggesting that maybe the align code depends on `indent-tabs-mode` (dunno).

If `align.el` relies on `indent-tabs-mode` being non-`nil` then you might just write commands that first call `align` or `align-regexp` and then, over the region affected, call `untabify`. IOW, let it insert `TAB` chars, but then convert them to `SPC` chars.

Instead of defining your own commands (and binding those to keys, e.g., the keys that might normally be bound to `align` and `align-regexp`), you could advise those commands. But that's typically overkill, and it can have nasty unexpected effects if some other code invokes those functions.

In general, if it's just for *your own interactive use* then you are better off defining and using your own commands, ***not*** advising standard commands/functions.

Luckily, Emacs supports dynamic binding, in addition to lexical binding, so you often need only bind a variable around the standard command/function whose behavior you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

In your "current" example, which we must presume has indentation the way you want it, we can see that you're *actually* indenting your code with spaces, despite setting `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)`.

So your claim that "I'm using this style and won't change [indent-tabs-mode] to nil" seems flawed to me -- even if it's set to `t`, you are apparently clobbering that behaviour somehow -- except where it's being used for alignment, which you *don't want*.

So despite your insistence, I can only say: `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)` in your `c-mode` and `c++-mode` hooks -- because that *is* what you want, so far as I can tell.

If you really won't do that, then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129994 for a way to ensure that alignments are always done with spaces.

Comment: "If you really won't do that, then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129994 for a way to ensure that alignments are always done with spaces."  I already did this, but it stills align with tabs. And my solution is not smart, it is just a workaround.

Comment: Well I can't replicate your problem.  Running `emacs -Q` in `c-mode` with `indent-tabs-mode` set to `t` and using the advice I linked to, indentation is done with tabs and alignment is done with spaces, exactly as I would expect.  I presume that something in your configuration is overriding this. Assuming you get the same result as me under `emacs -Q` then use recursive bisection on your config to isolate the cause of your problem.